# Open a socket with the name socket:[4023]

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I'm working on a linux system and want to open a socket for IPC. The process ID of the process I want to communicate with is 123. The process already opened the socket. I know that it is possible to send the file descriptor via unix domain sockets or dbus. But:

Is there also a way to open the socket by the name gotten from /proc/123/fd/15 ? If I call “ls -l” in  /proc/123/fd/ the symlink looks like “15 -> socket:[4023]”. Is there a way to open “socket:[4023]” ?

Edit: I am tried to do this in C.

Regards,
Maz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part in square brackets is the inode number of the socket. You can obtain the remote endpoint (for connected sockets), local address (for listening sockets) or path (for Unix sockets) using

```
ss -nae  | grep 4023 | awk '{print $5}'
```

or using `netstat -nae` if you do not have `ss` installed. netstat's output is more non-uniform though.

Both programs extract this information from `/proc/net/tcp`, `/proc/net/unix`, et al. To obtain the information using C, parse these files directly. They come with a readable header, so the columns should be clear; the idea is the same: Search for the line with the matching inode and extract the endpoint.

Comment: Thank you. I edited my post: I am trying to open the socket in C. I just tried the netstat way on my system and it works. But using netstat from C seems to by an inconvenient way for me.

Comment: See my edit: You'll have to open a file in `/proc/net` and parse it to retrieve the information fom C.